# Django project css and js not loading

Tags: python, django

Had a similar question with an older version of Django...

trying to get my site to load with its css and js

This is the structure of my project

```
gradMVPV1
--> .idea
--> catalog
    views
    models
    apps
    ....
--> gradMVPV1
    settings
    urls
    wsgi
    ....
--> templates
---->static
     css
     js
     ...
---->index.html
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

this is what I have on settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/static')
```

Here is a screenshot of my page

[image: screenshot]

Not sure if this helps at all but this is the css on my index.html file

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendors/linericon/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendors/nice-select/css/nice-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendors/animate-css/animate.css">
<!-- main css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
```

I have made these changes based on the answers given

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
STATIC_URL = 'templates/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/static')
```

I have also made changes to my index.html file to this effect

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendors/linericon/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
.....
```

I am however still getting the same issue, the index page loads with not css, js or images

Comment: Can you try removing the first / from /templates/static. That's pointing to the root of your filesystem

Comment: @anowlinorbit I had already tried that

Comment: First I recommend using the debug console in your browser and see the exact error, but it is most likely a 404. In your template file, if you're reference a static resource, you need to load the static files with {% load staticfiles %}. Put this at the top of your template file. And to access static content, use   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
 where main.css sits in the folder templates/static/css/main.css

Comment: @anowlinorbit not sure I am reading you correctly, do you mind adding that as an answer

Comment: Will do. Also checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Your above index.html won't be able to access the static files. Check out the solution I offered and the link above to see how you access your static content.

Comment: Use `{% load static %}` not `{% load staticfiles %}`. Also, since your static files directory isn't a standard `/static` directory inside one of your apps, you need to set `STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates", "static"),)`. And do us a favor, use `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` But I'd **strongly recommend** you move your static folder **outside** of templates folder, the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: If you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) carefully, you'll see that `STATIC_ROOT` is **not needed** for serving static files in development.

Answer (score 2):

Try add 
`STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates", "static"),)`
Your settings file, i read from this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: should I replace STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT or add this in addition to these two

Comment: @Emm ```STATIC_URL``` and ```STATIC_ROOT``` in ```setting.py``` works well. don't know about the other one

Comment: You can keep your STATIC_URL and using `href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}>"` instead of `href="static/css/style.css">` read this template language https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/

Comment: And add this to {% load staticfiles %} your html file as guy's answer below i forgot about this

Comment: I have tried that, still getting the same issue. Updated my question with what I tried

Comment: Are you running DEBUB = True in your settings file? Django will not serve static when DEBUG=False

Comment: @anowlinorbit I am running with DEBUG = True

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Django's static files in your templates, then you need to first load the static files with

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Then, if you wish to use a static item, for example `main.css` in `templates/static/css/main.css` you would use this syntax.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

As an example, here is an edited base.html file of mine:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello Emm</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still getting the same issue...noticed that I get these messages as my terminal updates -> Not Found: /img/f-icons/icon6.png  ...this is happening presumably for all css, img and js files. Are there any changes I need to make to settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

Check your static url and replace it to STATIC_URL = 'templates/static/' or edit settings.py and put static folder into gradMVPV1 folder.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

You should have this structure
gradMVPV1
--> .idea
--> catalog
    views
    models
    apps
    ....
--> gradMVPV1
    settings
    urls
    wsgi
    ....

---->static
     css
     js
--> templates
     ...
---->index.html
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

Comment: made these changes, but still getting the same issue. Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Check your static url and replace it to STATIC_URL = '/static/' and edit settings.py.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

You may to have this stucture
project
--> name_project1
    static
       name_project1
           file1.css
           file2.css
    templates
       name_project1
           base.html
           ...
--> project
    settings.py
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    ...
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```